# Tomcat: Restarting server did't resolve this problem: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat 8.5.81: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My Log:   (help me, I fight with this issue four days)
https://github.com/anatoliy19/testCRUD.git

```
[2022-07-29 11:36:02,466] Artifact 2.3.1_my:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\0d9b3e61-4b53-48c5-9034-92971ff13805"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Users\admin\.jdks\openjdk-18.0.1.1"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.600 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.81
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.603 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 8 2022 21:30:15 UTC
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.604 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.81.0
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.608 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ РћРЎ:             10.0
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log РђСЂС…РёС‚РµРєС‚СѓСЂР°:           amd64
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Users\admin\.jdks\openjdk-18.0.1.1
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ JVM:            18.0.1.1+2-6
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\0d9b3e61-4b53-48c5-9034-92971ff13805
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\0d9b3e61-4b53-48c5-9034-92971ff13805\conf\logging.properties
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\0d9b3e61-4b53-48c5-9034-92971ff13805\jmxremote.password
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\0d9b3e61-4b53-48c5-9034-92971ff13805\jmxremote.access
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.613 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.614 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\0d9b3e61-4b53-48c5-9034-92971ff13805
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\temp
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.33] using APR version [1.7.0].
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [{4}].
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.615 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.717 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:04.754 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 968 ms
29-Jul-2022 11:36:05.100 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:05.102 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/8.5.81]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:05.131 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:05.169 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 413 ms
Connected to server
[2022-07-29 11:36:05,379] Artifact 2.3.1_my:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
29-Jul-2022 11:36:15.148 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\manager]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:16.255 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [229] milliseconds.
29-Jul-2022 11:36:16.453 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\manager] has finished in [1В 304] ms
29-Jul-2022 11:36:19.739 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
29-Jul-2022 11:36:21.815 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:22.127 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
29-Jul-2022 11:36:22.740 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
29-Jul-2022 11:36:24.110 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
29-Jul-2022 11:36:26.137 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:27.219 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
29-Jul-2022 11:36:27.272 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
29-Jul-2022 11:36:27.405 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2022-07-29 11:36:27,508] Artifact 2.3.1_my:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2022-07-29 11:36:27,508] Artifact 2.3.1_my:war exploded: Deploy took 22,129 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved with Tomcat 9.0.65

The strict localhost:8080 remains 404, application runs by address
http://localhost:8080/..._war_exploded/